# Datatype for lookup table/index into array

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Assume I have a class 'Widget'. In my application, I create a lot of Widgets which (for cache locality and other reasons) I keep in a vector.

For efficient lookups I would like to implement an index datastructure. For the sake of the question, let's assume it is a simple lookup table from int indices to Widget elements in the abovementioned vector.
My question is: What should the contents of the lookup table be.
In other words, with which type should I replace the question mark in

```
using LookupTable = std::vector<?>
```

I see the following options:

- References (Widget&, or rather as it has to be assignable: reference_wrapper<Widget>)
- Pointers (Widget*)
- Indices in the Widget vector (size_t)
- Iterator objects pointing into the Widget vector (std::vector<Widget>::iterator)

Among these options, indices seem to be the only option that don't get invalidated by a vector resize. I might actually be able to avoid resizes, however, implementing the lookup table like that means making assumptions about the vector implementation which seems unreasonable from a 'decoupled design' standpoint.

OTOH indices are not typesafe: If the thing I get out of the lookup table was a reference I could only use it to access the corresponding widget. Using size_t values I can do nonsensical operations like multiplying the result by 3. Also consider the following two signatures:

```
void doSomethingWithLookupResult(Widget& lookupResult);
void doSomethingWithLookupResult(size_t lookupResult);
```

The former is significantly more descriptive.

In summary: Which datatype can I use for my lookup table to achieve both a decoupling from the vector implementation and type safety?

Comment: Can you provide an example for *how* you're actually using the LookupTable?

Comment: @Barry: The std::vector<?> table is a simplification. Nevertheless, say the widget has a priority value. Then, in my lookup table I want to quickly find the first Widget from the original list with the given priority. This would quite literally be a vector lookup: widgetByPriority[priority]. After that, I obviously want to work with the widget I found, e.g. compute its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that represents an index which also carries type information (in compile-time).

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct typed_index {
    typed_index(int i) : i(i) {}

    template <class CONTAINER>
    T &operator[](CONTAINER &c) { return c[i]; }
    template <class CONTAINER>
    const T &operator[](const CONTAINER &c) { return c[i]; }

    int i;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 = {0};
    std::vector<const char *> v2 = {"asd"};
    typed_index<int> i = 3;
    int z = i[v1];
    const char *s = i[v2]; // will fail
}
```

Comment: It produced me headhace till I figured that the `operator[]` was reversed... index is *outside* the square brackets and container *inside* them!

Comment: Technically C allows this syntax for arrays (it won't work for vectors though)

Comment: I know, but only for *old style arrays* 'cause `arr[1]` equals to `*(arr + 1)` so `1[arr]` equals to `*(1 + arr)` but it produces me headache anyway >_<

Comment: As for a type-safe indexes I've found interesting [this article](http://www.ilikebigbits.com/blog/2014/5/6/type-safe-identifiers-in-c) which can be used to implement [another verbose-but-functional solution](http://ideone.com/x6bIeF)

Comment: Tagging the index with the type seems like a good idea. The reversed operator[] is confusing, but not an essential part of the solution. It might be feasible to create a wrapper around the initial vector that only allows access via tagged indices...

Answer (score 2):

Use std::vector::size_type (not size_t). std::vector::size_type may be size_t in most implementations, but for portability and future-proofing sake, we'll do it right.

Go ahead and make a typedef:
using WidgetIndex = std::vector::size_type;

so that this looks reasonable:

void doSomethingWithLookupResult(WidgetIndex lookupResult);

This avoids the vector resize issue which, while you down play it in your question, will eventually come back to bite you.

Don't play games with some user defined type such as tohava (very cleverly) proposes, unless you plan to use this idiom a great deal in your code base. Here is why not:

- The problem that you are addressing (type-safety) is real and we'd like a solution to it if it is "free," but compared to other opportunities C++ programmers have to shoot themselves in the foot, this isn't that big an issue.
- You'll be wasting time. Your time to design the class and then the time of every user of your code base (including yourself after you've forgotten the implementation in a few months) that will stare at that code and have to puzzle it out.
- At some point in the future you'll trip over that "interesting" corner case that none of us can see now by staring at this code.

All that said, if you are going to use this idiom often in your code base (you have many classes that are stored in very static vectors or arrays), then it may make sense to make this investment. In that case the maintenance burden is spread over more code and the possibility of using the wrong index type with the wrong container is greater.

Comment: I will accept tohava's answer as it provides a concrete answer that matches the requirements formulated in the original question. However, I do see your point and I will keep your advice in mind.